# Create dynamic table editable Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, dynamic

I have a dynamic table where data is downloaded through a web service, how can I edit a cell, or how else do I do this?

```
            tabla.agregarCabecera(R.array.cabecera_);
            do {

                String A = c.getString(0);
                String B = c.getString(1);
                String C = c.getString(2);
                String D = c.getString(3);
                String E = c.getString(4);
                String F = c.getString(5);

                ArrayList<String> elementos = new ArrayList<String>();

                elementos.add(A);
                elementos.add(B);
                elementos.add(C);
                elementos.add(D);
                elementos.add(E);
                elementos.add(F);
                tabla.agregarFilaTabla(elementos);
                array.add(A);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are simply putting an arrayList (in which I presume elements are cell content) in a row and expecting the row object to unwind your arraylist and put in the right cells.

Sadly it doesn't works like this.
The best solution to me, seems in this case:

- cycling through the array with a generalized for cycle ( perfect for 
  this situation )
- create a cell for every element (since you declared |string|
  type, i assume you haven't numbers to manipulate as numbers,    so
  you won't need String.valueof() );
- ADD the cell to the row;
- AND THEN ADD the row to the table;

But since you've already got the data when you declared the strings from A to F, you won't even need to pass in the arrayList, you could put the string directly into cells, adding them into row, and add the row into the table